# Laravel nested foreach?

Tags: laravel, nested-loops, laravel-blade

Having trouble with nested `foreach` and despite the other questions, I can't get my head around what could be wrong with my `Customers.blade` file:

```
@foreach ($customers as $company)
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ $company->name }}</td>
        <td>@if ($company->active == 1) YES @else NO @endif</td>
        <td>View</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Remove</td> 
    </tr>
    @foreach ($customersites->customer_id as $company->id)
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ $customersites->sitename }}</td>
                <td>@if ($customersites->active == 1) YES @else NO @endif</td>
                <td>View</td>
                <td>Edit</td>
                <td>Remove</td> 
            </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This results in:

> Property [customer_id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: >C:\Apache24\htdocs\truckrun\resources\views\customers.blade.php)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please add a `var_dump($customers)` and `var_dump($customersites)` to your question? Knowing the structure of these collections would help understand what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 @foreach ($customers as $company)
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ $company->name }}</td>
            <td>@if ($company->active == 1) YES @else NO @endif</td>
            <td>View</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Remove</td> 
        </tr>
        @foreach ($customersites as $company->id)
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@if(isset($customersites->sitename) && $customersites->sitename !="") {{ $customersites->sitename }} @endif</td>
                    <td>@if ($customersites->active == 1) YES @else NO @endif</td>
                    <td>View</td>
                    <td>Edit</td>
                    <td>Remove</td> 
                </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish for the insane speed on your reply... I've edit my question as I posted wrong.... my real question is why my second foreach ($customersites->customer_id as $company->id) does not work?

Comment: set foreach like @foreach((array)$customersites->customer_id as $company)
  
@endforeach